# Is there a way to use a variable into access_control paths so I can compare it

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a symfony application I'm heading for the finals.
Right now I'm working with the security issues, granting that nobody will see more than it needs.

I have a specific user that can only access a specific route, that I'have manage using Roles, however, I'll have lots of that users, and need to check if the current user is accessing its own data, and denies the access otherwise.

For example, I'll have many users with the same ROLE, lets say I'll have many ROLE_EMPLOYER, each one will have its own access to the system but, they need to be able to access just its own show page and employees without being able to access other employer page.

I researched the security authorization checker and saw that I can denie the access into the actions of the controlers, but I was willing if there is something simpler like that:

```
security.yml
   access_control:
   - { path: ^/fornecedor/{id},  allow_if: "{id} == token.getUser.getId and has_role('ROLE_FORNECEDOR')" }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use access control for methods via annotations

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function indexAction()
```

And for class too

```
/**
* Class DefaultController
* @package Canoe\WebBundle\Controller
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
class DefaultController extends Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach.

I would say that you dont need to compares user "Id" into "access_control", instead, you could assign a specific role in your Login action and just check if the current path requires a specific role like ROLE_ADMIN in order to be accessed, otherwise, deny the access to that route.

For example, in the login Action you could find the user by id and retrieves roles name:

```
//Controller
public function loginAction(Request $request) {
    ......
    $aRolesName = $oEntityLogin->getRepository('AppBundle:TitUserRol')->findRolesByUserId($oUser->getUseUserId());
    $aRoleNameToken = count($aRolesName) > 0 ? $aRolesName : array('ROLE_USER');
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($formlogin['username'], null, 'secured_area', $aRoleNameToken);
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    ......
```

Check if the route requires a specific role
(security.yml)

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }   
    - { path: ^/home, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER] }
```

Comment: Hi @rescobar, thank you for the answer. The problem is that, I'll have many users with the same ROLE, lets say I'll have many ROLE_EMPLOYER, each one will have its own access to the system but, they need to be able to access just its own show page and employees without being able to access other employer page.